# When charging an entrance in Zoomaka do I give change?

Tags: zoomaka

Let's say I have a full set of Monkeys in [Zoomaka](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/233048/zoomaka) the total sum of all cards are 3+2+2+2 = 9 So all players should give me 9 Zoomas right? If one of my opponents only has two five Zooma cards in their bank am I required to give change?

[image: Full monkey section]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

I presume from the title you've played the relevant Entrance card to charge the fee.

From [the rules](http://www.boardgamecapital.com/game_rules/zoomaka.pdf), page 10:

> When paying a debt no change is returned.

The player could choose to pay with assets from their zoo instead of using the full 5-cost banked card, though this might make more sense if the total cost were, for example, 7.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote the rules so I was planning on answering my self. We are making an FAQ about the game. But thank for your reply.

Comment: @Pablo Jomer, When you are composing a Question, there's a checkbox at the bottom labeled "Answer your own question". It allows you to post a Question and an Answer at the same time.

Comment: @Pablo Jomer, Also note that the new tag won't survive auto-reaping unless you give it a description (or use it for a second question).

Comment: @ikegame Thanks I knew this already as I have been a member of the stack overflow community for about five years. Thanks for being helpful though. <3